# Django return render/httpresponse and Json into a single Jsonresponse

Tags: django, httpresponse, jsonresponse

I'm new to Django and try to understand how to return 2 different kind of response type inside one return Jsonresponse :

view.py

```
def article_filter_mobile(request):

    # Here I'm trying to get the total records number of my DB
    number_of_rec = Record.objects.count()
    # Need to access {{number_of_rec}} in test.html
    count = render(request, 'test.html', {'number_of_rec': number_of_rec})

    # here I'm listing all datas of my DB 
    data = dict()
    locations = Record.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM myDb")
    available_lessons = [model_to_dict(l) for l in locations]
    # Need to access {{available_lessons|safe}} in a JS script inside grid_mobile.html
    data['html_table'] = render_to_string('grid_mobile.html', 
       {'available_lessons': available_lessons},request=request)

    # I think my problem is here as data and count are not in the same format 
    return JsonResponse(data,count)
```

Can someone help me to understand what is wrong in this code ?
Thanks

Comment: `number_of_rec` should be `number_of_rec = Record.objects.all().count()`

Comment: So there is no problem mixing a simple render + a render_to_string inside a jsonresponse like i did ?

Comment: I think, In Django, when you want to return multiple types of responses in a single view function, you can't directly combine different types like `HttpResponse` (for rendering `HTML`) and `JsonResponse` (for returning JSON data) in the same return statement.

Comment: Tried to replace number_of_rec by  number_of_rec = Record.objects.all().count() but still not working.

Comment: Please *don't*. If you want to return JSON blobs, make a separate view, and trigger it through AJAX, this is what is often done with frameworks like Vue, React and Angular: define a path that returs the page, and then some views that return the required data.

Comment: @willem that’s already what I’m doing with the second part of the code (ajax) for getting the datas.
Just wondering how to add a second query (count) to make it in one view and avoid to remake all the whole process just to have a simple integer …